# how to troubleshoot Android debugger problems?

Tags: android, debugging

Can anyone recommend how to troubleshoot debugger issues, i.e., why 
the debugger doesn't always stop at breakpoints or why it seems to 
randomly disconnect.  I often have to stop the emulator and try to 
start the debugger and emulator again.  Sometimes the debugger doesn't 
seem to re-attach, too.

Comment: what debugger options (in Debug Configurations) have you set?

Answer (score 0):

Usually clean and re-build on the project works. It might be that your source files and the code that runs on the emulator are not the same? Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with the debug service. 
Try the reset ADB option available in the DDMS perspective or try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` commands from the command prompt.